# Stored procedure : Select data from Table "A" and insert data on Table "B"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I haven't touched stored procedures and functions for a very long time.
So I decided to make a mini-training database for myself.

At the moment, I'm trying to create a procedure that comes in and selects data from one table (Test_trigger) and says that if the sum for a colour exceeds a threshold, then I write an alert row to another table (Test_alm_trigger)

Here are my 2 tables creation script :

```
create table Test_trigger (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Couleur VARCHAR(50),
    Horodate DATETIME,
    Nombre DECIMAL(6,2),
    Seuil_fixe INT
);

create table Test_alm_trigger (
    id_alm INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Label VARCHAR(100),
    Horodate DATETIME,
    Seuil DECIMAL(6,2)
);
```

To be more precise, the goal is :

when a colour ([Couleur]), such as "Blue", has a sum of the [Nombre] column above the threshold entered ([Seuil_fixe]), then the procedure runs and inserts a row in the Test_alm_trigger table with a [Label], the date the addition was made ( SYSDATETIME() ) and the sum of the [Nombre] column.

I have created this procedure but I am not sure how it works or if it is good or not

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ajoutL_triggerAlm
(
    @Couleur nvarchar(50),
    @Label nvarchar(200) = 'Dépassement de seuil',
    @Seuil float(4),
    @Seuil_fixe float(4),
    @Msg nvarchar(200)

)
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT [Couleur] 
        FROM Test_trigger
        GROUP BY [Couleur], [Nombre], [Seuil_fixe]
        HAVING [Couleur] = @Couleur AND
                SUM([Nombre]) = @Seuil AND
                [Seuil_fixe] = @Seuil_fixe AND
                @Seuil > @Seuil_fixe
)
    BEGIN
        SET @Msg = 'Debug'
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Test_alm_trigger
        VALUES (@Label, SYSDATETIME(), @Seuil)
    END
END
```

If you have any answers, tips... I'll take them.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you plan to invoke your procedure - is this something you will do from an Agent job or should you be implementing an `after update trigger` instead of a procedure?

Comment: Its not clear how the column `Seuil_fixe` is used compared to the parameter `@Seuil_fixe`? You store a threshold *and* pass in a threshold?

Comment: @Stu The procedure has to trigger itself, at the moment I have only tested it with manually entered data and "exec".

DaleK in my table, I store the fixed threshold indeed. For exemple for the color "Red" the threshold is 2450. And if the sum of every value in the "Nombre" column is greater than 2450 for the red color then i'd like to insert a row in a table to say that have passed this threshold.
On reflection, is it therefore unnecessary to call a parameter when I have the column?

Comment: @Brck so how many rows per colour in Test_trigger could there be? It seems more than one because you have suggested a sum, but given you also store the threshold, Seuil_fixe, there, you could end up with a different value per row of the same colour? What would really make this question clear is sample data and expected results, which illustrates all use cases, including edge cases.

Comment: @DaleK As I am training with this exercise, I write the data by hand with this type of insert :
`
insert into Test_trigger (Couleur, Horodate, Nombre, Seuil_fixe) values ('Orange', '2020-05-01 11:36:01', 723.93, 3000);
insert into Test_trigger (Couleur, Horodate, Nombre, Seuil_fixe) values ('Blue', '2021-03-09 08:36:33', 550.74, 2500);
...
`

I use about 100 rows on one site (https://www.mockaroo.com/) and I don't really have a row limit. I have indicated the fixed threshold in the base, but I think that for the exercise it's more interesting to declare a variable in the procedure

Comment: @DaleK so if you do this request : [link](https://ibb.co/NFjrFtn) (in Test_trigger) you see that one or many colors have a sum greater than the threshold (Seuil_fixe). And once this happens I would like a procedure to run to insert a row to an alert table (Test_alm_trigger) to say that a colour has exceeded its threshold and have this returns : [link](https://ibb.co/fC55086)

Comment: @Brck I'm not totally following you, but if you use a parameter instead of a column value to specify the colour limit then I think the SP I have shown below works.

Comment: @DaleK actually your SP doesn't work at all, and I don't understand at all the whole "insert" package.

Comment: @Brck "doesn't work at all" is not useful. When reporting bugs (and you'll be glad of this yourself when a client/user reports bugs on your software) you need to explain exactly what you did, exactly what results/behaviour you observed, and what results/behaviour you expected. And if there are aspects you don't understand please ask.

Answer (score 0):

The main change I would suggest is making your procedure set-based rather than procedural. Relational databases are optimised for set-based operations so you should try and get into the mindset of operating that way yourself.

I've added other best practices.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ajoutL_triggerAlm
(
    @Couleur nvarchar(50)
    , @Label nvarchar(200) = 'Dépassement de seuil'
    -- Almost never use float, its not a precise numeric amount and should only be used when specifically required
    , @Seuil decimal(8,4)
    -- Almost never use float, its not a precise numeric amount and should only be used when specifically required
    , @Seuil_fixe decimal(8,4)
    , @Msg nvarchar(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Best practice (I'll leave the meaning as an exercise)
    -- SQL Server recommendation is to ";" terminate all statements
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    -- Best practice, always list the columns you are inserting into
    -- Use set-based operations instead of procedural where you can
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test_alm_trigger (Label, Horodate, Seuil)
        SELECT @Label, SYSDATETIME(), @Seuil
        -- Question states when SUM([Nombre] above the threshold @Seuil_fixe - so I think this is the logic
        -- Although its not clear where the column Seuil_fixe comes into it
        WHERE (
            SELECT SUM([Nombre])
            FROM Test_trigger
            WHERE [Couleur] = @Couleur
        ) > @Seuil_fixe;

    -- Detect failure using @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @Msg = CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN 'Debug' ELSE NULL END;

    -- Return a status, can use other values to indicate errors
    RETURN 0;
END;
```